# C++ warning and logj4 log level

Tags: java, c++, logging

While I was studying Spring, I found out that there was a level in the log. So I searched about it. And I know there's a warning level. Also C++ presents warning in some cases, such as

```
vector<string> str;
for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){...}
```

[image]

So my question is: Is waring in c++ is kind of log and same level with warning log level?

Comment: They are two different things. The Log Level you are referring to is simply the categorization of the entries on your log file. This warning you are looking at is related to the language syntax and usage which can possibly result in compile errors

Comment: @MarcosBarbero warnings in C++ have nothing do to with compiler errors (unless you instruct the compiler to treat them as such), they're just... *warnings* that tell you you're doing some operation which is syntactically legal but may not be the best thing to do. Like in the example, which is doing something syntactically correct but the compiler is telling you "are you sure you *mean* this?"

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, this is exactly the same in Java.